# Xamarin.ios Close UIAlertController ActionSheet when tap on screen

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, uialertcontroller

I'm creating a UIAlertController with ActionSheet style:

```
UIAlertController actionSheetAlert = UIAlertController.Create(null, null, UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);
```

I'm adding an action to it:

```
UIAlertAction alertAction = UIAlertAction.Create("Action", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, DoSomting);
var alertImage = UIImage.FromBundle("image")
                 .ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
alertImage = ResizeImage(sortingAlertImage, 32, 32)
                 .ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
alertAction.SetValueForKey(alertImage, new NSString("image"));
alertAction.SetValueForKey(UIColor.Black, new NSString("titleTextColor"));
actionSheetAlert.AddAction(alertAction);
```

And display it:

```
PresentViewController(_actionSheetAlert, true, null);
```

---

How can I close the UIAlertController  when tapping on screen?

I can do it by adding a "cancel" action like this:

```
var cancelAlertAction = UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null);
cancelAlertAction.SetValueForKey(UIColor.Black, new NSString("titleTextColor"));
actionSheetAlert.AddAction(cancelAlertAction);
```

But I don't want to display the cancel action.

Answer (score 1):

While Hussain's suggestion works in a really basic setting it might be interfered with when you have other views under the alert with gesture recognisers attached. What I usually do in situations like this (works well on for example closing the keyboard as well) is add a full screen invisible button to my content view.

```
public readonly UIButton CloseButton;

public MyView()
{
    CloseButton = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
    CloseButton.Alpha = 0; //or CloseButton.Hidden = true;

    AddSubview(CloseButton);
}
```

You can add the handler already in ViewDidAppear because invisible views can not be interacted with.

```
UIAlertController actionSheetAlert;

public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    contentView.CloseButton.TouchUpInside += CloseAlert;
}

void CloseAlert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Notice the missing null check because the alert should never be null here. If it is you have a problem in your code and you'll find it easily.

    actionSheetAlert.DismissViewController(true, () => { });

    //Hide the button here.
}
```

And when you open your alert dialog then you just make the button visible. If you want to be fancy and make it extra clear to the user that tapping outside the dialog closes it then you can make the button black and set the alpha to 30% when the dialog opens.

```
void OpenDialog() {
    //Create dialog, add actions etc.

    UIView.Animate(0.3, () => { CloseButton.Alpha = 0.3f});
}
```

And if you keep the cancel button on the alert then remember to hide the close button there as well with either Hidden = true or Alpha = 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use bellow code for swift:
You need to add tap gesture for the same.

```
func showAlertBtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "This is title", message: "This is message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:{
        alert.view.superview?.userInteractionEnabled = true
        alert.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.alertControllerBackgroundTapped)))
    })
}

func alertControllerBackgroundTapped()
{
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

An Alert can not be dismissed normally.
Or create a custom alert view.

Comment: But this is not swift @Hussain Chhatriwala

Comment: I just need to convey that add a tap gesture on parent view, that can help you for closing it on tap.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution thanks to https://forums.xamarin.com/profile/LandLu:

```
UIAlertController actionSheetAlert = UIAlertController.Create(null, null, UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);

PresentViewController(actionSheetAlert, true, () => {
UITapGestureRecognizer recognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer((tapRecognizer) =>
{
    actionSheetAlert.DismissViewController(true, null);
});
// After testing, The first subview of the screen can be used for adding gesture to dismiss the action sheet
actionSheetAlert.View.Superview.Subviews[0].AddGestureRecognizer(recognizer);
});
```